# Solve a second order linear differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve on $\phi(x)$:
$$-\phi''(x) + (W^2(x)+W'(x))\phi(x)=0$$
I have no idea, I could only notice that $\phi(x) = 0$ is a solution.

Comment: It's better to add to your question your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\phi''(x) + (W^2(x)+W'(x))\phi(x)=0$$
$$-u''(x) + (W^2(x)+W'(x))u(x)=0$$
Note that  ( I used $u$ instead of $\phi$):

$$\left(\dfrac {u'}{u}\right)'=\dfrac {u''}{u}-\dfrac {u'^2}{u^2}$$
$$\dfrac {u''}{u}=\left(\dfrac {u'}{u}\right)'+\dfrac {u'^2}{u^2}$$
So that you have :
$$\dfrac {u''}{u}=W'+W^2$$
$$\left(\dfrac {u'}{u}\right)'+\dfrac {u'^2}{u^2}=W'+W^2$$
One of the solution is:
$$\implies \dfrac {u'}{u}=W$$
This is a first differential equation that you can easily solve in function of $W$. Maybe you can use the method of reduction of order to find the general solution of the differential equation.